# SymPy module, identify equation as linear or non-linear?

Tags: python, sympy

Using `SymPy` module, is there a method to tell me if the equation is linear or non-linear? If not what's your recommendation to implement such a method. I noticed from documentation that `solve()` returned values change according to the coefficients.

I just need it as a simple introduction to high school students. to answer a question I found to label whether the function is linear or not.

thank you very much.

Comment: It would really help if you'd add some representative example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to do next. To just get a True/False answer try `Poly(expr, x).is_linear`. This will expand the expression and tell you if it is linear in `x`.

`linear_coeffs` will either raise an error if non-linear terms are encountered or else give you the linear coefficients of the given variables, `solveset.linear_coeffs(2*x+3*y+z**2,x,y) -> [2, 3, z**2]` (where the last element is the constant term in the expression).

`linear_eq_to_matrix` and `solve_linear` are also possibilities.